# How to set multiple column lines (grid lines) in Beyond Compare 4?

Tags: editor, diff, beyondcompare, difftool, beyondcompare4

Currently I'm able to set one column line already using the **Options > Tweaks > Show column line at** option.

[image: Beyond Compare 4 - Options window > Tweaks tab]

How do I set multiple column lines / grid lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond Compare only supports setting one column line. It isn't possible to set multiple column (grid) lines in the Text Compare.